# Template specification of any kind of array

Tags: c++, types, casting, type-conversion

I'm trying to get rid of `void*` + `size` approach to storing arbitrary array types in the same container.

At the moment it looks somewhat like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

struct fat_pointer {
  void *data;
  size_t size;
  size_t count;

  fat_pointer() : data(nullptr), size(0), count(0)
  {
  }

  fat_pointer(void *data_, size_t size_, size_t count_) :
    data(data_), size(size_), count(count_)
  {
  }

  bool valid() const {
    return data != nullptr;
  }

  template <typename T>
  const T as() {
    return static_cast<T>(data);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // data can be anything, these two are just for example
  const double v1[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
  const int v2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  std::map<std::string, fat_pointer> data;

  data.insert(std::pair<std::string, fat_pointer>("V1", fat_pointer((void*)v1, sizeof(v1[0]), sizeof(v1) / sizeof(v1[0]))));
  data.insert(std::pair<std::string, fat_pointer>("V2", fat_pointer((void*)v2, sizeof(v2[0]), sizeof(v2) / sizeof(v2[0]))));

  auto values = data["V1"];

  if (values.valid()) {
    std::cout << values.as<double*>()[2] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This approach is super error-prone, does not provide any kind of validation, does not allow to easily count or apply algorithms on the elements, so I really want to get rid of it.

Is there some way to tell the compiler that the value will be an array of an arbitrary type? OR is there any other way I can try to avoid the `fat_pointer` hack?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like `std::any`.

Comment: according to `std::any` description, I'll have to create something like `std::vector<std::any>` which is definitely not an option as it'll make working with such data hard as hell

Comment: `std::any` can hold a (smart) pointer and has the type checking that your `fat_pointer` is missing.

Comment: I'm using arrays that are coming from 3rd party libraries, they should not be `delete[]` from my code. On top of that `std::any` won't do as I'm checking `count` in quite a few places. I thought to use something like `std::any_of`, but I have too many types there + other code may need to add some more :(

Comment: unique_ptr does not imply operator delete. You can define a custom deleter.

Comment: If you want a container like `std::map` to hold multiple arrays of different types, then you are basically stuck with using `std::any` or `std::variant` as the array element type if you don't want to use `void*`.  Container elements have to be the same type, just like array elements do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier storing begin() and end() of those arrays in a wrapper object and operating on those instead of trying this C++-on-C stuff?

Comment: @DevSolar `begin()` and `end()` have types too, so I'll have to store `std::any` casted later to `std::pair` which is possible, but usage will be even worse than now.

Comment: The compiler needs to know the type at compile time in order to know how much memory to allocate. That's part of the strong typing. If you don't ever know the types in the data, you're stuck with the pointer/size type. (I wouldn't put count in the same struct for the basic type, I would declare a separate "array" type for that)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the types of your arrays up front, you could use `std::variant`. You can change your `fat_pointer` struct to hold a variant of type `std::pair<T*, T*>` where the `first` and `second` members of your pair will hold pointers to the start and one past the end of the array respectively. Then have a templated constructor to capture the type of the array.

`std::variant` will give you the type safety you want. Plus, now that you're storing the begin and end pointers, you can use them with standard algorithms.

If you're going to treat all the arrays is a uniform way, you don't need separate visitor functions in `std::visit`. You can get type `T` in `std::pair<T*, T*>` using:

```
using T = std::decay_t<decltype(*arg.first)>;
```

and then use `T`.

Here's a example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using PairVariant = std::variant<std::pair<const int*, const int*>, std::pair<const double*, const double*>>;

struct fat_pointer {
  PairVariant mPtrs;
  
  template<typename T>
  fat_pointer(T* begin, T* end): mPtrs{std::pair<T*, T*>(begin, end)} {}

};

int main()
{
    const double v1[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
    const int v2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    fat_pointer ptr1{v1, std::end(v1)};
    fat_pointer ptr2{v2, std::end(v2)};

    std::vector<fat_pointer> vec{ptr1, ptr2};

    for (auto& v: vec) {
        std::visit([] (auto&& arg) {
            using T = std::decay_t<decltype(*arg.first)>;  //type of T in std::pair<T*, T*>
            std::copy (arg.first, arg.second, std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));
        }, v.mPtrs);

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Live [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/do5TEP).

---

If you don't know the type of the arrays you're going to store in advance, then I think you will have to use `std::any`. You can store a pointer to the array and its size, and have a template member function to do a `std::any_cast`. But if there are arrays of many different types, you will end up testing against those types at runtime and that can be pretty ugly!

```
struct fat_pointer {
    std::any mPtr;
    std::size_t mSize;

    template<typename T>
    fat_pointer(T* begin, T* end): mPtr{begin}, mSize(end-begin) {}

    template<typename T>
    T AnyCast()
    {
        if (T* ptr = std::any_cast<T>(&mPtr)) {
            return *ptr;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/d8xG9r).

Comment: I don't know all the possible types upfront, that's the trick.

Comment: @Daniel But don't you have a finite set of arrays types? You can extend the `std::variant`  type in my answer as much as you like, but the compiler needs to know what type of array you have.

Comment: …unless the design of the program allows those types to be declared in other translation units.

Comment: @spectras If the types are not known at compile time, then I can't see an alternative to using `std::any`. As the OP said in his comments, this can lead to pretty ugly type checking. I've updated my answer to give an example. In my opinion, `std::variant` is better.

Comment: Indeed. Unrelated, but I'm surprised your answer did not attract any vote yet.